# Procedure to find a pair of matrices whose product has rank less than each matrix in the pair

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to figure out how to find two rank-deficient matrices (not necessarily square) which when multiplied will have rank less than either of the original matrices.

In other words I am looking for:

$$A \in R^{a \times b} , B \in R^{c \times d}: Rank(AB) < min(Rank(A),Rank(B))$$

Ideally, I would be interested in a procedure which could be used to generate such matrices. Examples or terminology I could search to learn more about the topic would also be very useful.

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a bit on the idea in [José Carlos Santos’ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3081267/265466), take any matrix $A$ with a nontrivial kernel and rank greater than zero. Let the columns of $B$ be any elements of $\ker A$, with at least one nonzero column so that the rank of $B$ is also positive. Then $AB=0$.

Alternatively, take any set of pairwise orthogonal vectors and split them up however you like among the rows of $A$ and columns of $B$. Once again, $AB=0$.

Comment: This was definitely helpful, I'm trying to think of how I can use your  second statement so that AB is not necessarily the zero matrix.

Comment: @Filip Place one of the nonzero vectors into both matrices. $AB$ then has rank one.

Answer (score 1):

You can take two non-zero matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=0$. For example, take$$A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I believe this is Nilpotency, and this is restricted to square matrices.

Comment: Not at all. You can also take$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: To generalize this, you can take arbitrarily many orthogonal vectors and distribute them between $A$ and $B$ as rows or columns, respectively. Fill up with zeros and there you go.

Comment: So in general, if the columns of B belong to the nullspace of A then AB = 0, but I have also been trying to think of an example where the result matrix is not the zero matrix. For example if $$A \in R^{4 \times 3}, B \in R^{3 \times 5}, Rank(A)=2, Rank(B)=3: Rank(AB)=1$$

Comment: This is actually impossible. If $B$ has Rank 3, it is surjective. As the rank of $A$ is $2$, $AB$ needs to have at least a two-dimensional range in this configuration.

Comment: Need to investigate this some more, this was very helpful!

Comment: @Klaus Could you explain how you made the statement: "AB needs to have at least a two-dimensional range in this configuration."

Comment: I'm thinking about it sort of as follows. If B is surjective, then its column space spans all of $R^3$. A is essentially a mapping of the column space of B, so mapping $R^3$ by A is going to exactly yield the column space of A, which is known to have dimension 2.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.